# Android Studio Error When Accessing the Internet

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I have been working on this android app for my school in Android studio and I want to get content off of the school's website. I used a simple piece of code to get the data and then parse the HTML document with Jsoup. Here is the code that I put in a class that I then accessed in the Main activity. Please excuse the poor code quality as I am a beginner.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Website {


//Variables
private URL url;
private String text;


//Constructor
public Website(String url) {
    try{
        this.url=new URL(url);
    }catch(MalformedURLException e){

    }

}

public String getParseData(){
    return this.text;
}

public void receiveContent(String elementclass){
    String html;
    try{


        InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
        BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line;


        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }

        html=sb.toString();

        Document doc= Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements content=doc.getElementsByClass(elementclass);
        this.text=content.text();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
```

}

So when I execute the code through my activity it has an error. I have tested the code in Eclipse and it worked as expected. When I run it on an Android device or emulator it crashes a gives a stack trace. When I remove the code or not call the class it works fine. It's only when I execute this code that I get more specifically in receiveContent method.

```
01-17 16:03:22.321    5195-5195/com.example.lazycody.rmhs_app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.lazycody.rmhs_app, PID: 5195
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lazycody.rmhs_app/com.example.lazycody.rmhs_app.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2438)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2497)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:168)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5678)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1166)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:390)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:343)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
        at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:190)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContent(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:169)
        at java.net.URL.getContent(URL.java:455)
        at com.example.lazycody.rmhs_app.Websiteinfo.getContent(Websiteinfo.java:41)
        at com.example.lazycody.rmhs_app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5586)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
```

Also, here is my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/school_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".YoutubePage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_youtube_page" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or why it works in Eclipse but not on Android. I really need some help with this because I have to finish this app by Tuesday! So anything will help, Thanks!!!!

Comment: Sir, it is because of this `Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.. so you can start by reading the answer by @Claudio and google the error and his solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to execute a network operation on the main thread. This is no allowed to avoid a long network operation to freeze the main thread causing the UI to become unresponsive.

You'll need to execute that operation in background. You can you an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or a separated thread.

> Android applications normally run entirely on a single thread by default the "UI thread" or "main thread"). This means anything your application is doing in the UI thread that takes a long time to complete can trigger the ANR dialog because your application is not giving itself a chance to handle the input event or intent broadcasts.
>
> Therefore, any method that runs in the UI thread should do as little work as possible on that thread. In particular, activities should do as little as possible to set up in key life-cycle methods such as onCreate() and onResume(). Potentially long running operations such as network or database operations, or computationally expensive calculations such as resizing bitmaps should be done in a worker thread (or in the case of databases operations, via an asynchronous request).
>
> The most effecive way to create a worker thread for longer operations is with the AsyncTask class. Simply extend AsyncTask and implement the doInBackground() method to perform the work. To post progress changes to the user, you can call publishProgress(), which invokes the onProgressUpdate() callback method. From your implementation of onProgressUpdate() (which runs on the UI thread), you can notify the user. For example:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    // Do the long-running work in here
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        int count = urls.length;
        long totalSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
            publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
            // Escape early if cancel() is called
            if (isCancelled()) break;
        }
        return totalSize;
    }

    // This is called each time you call publishProgress()
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
    }

    // This is called when doInBackground() is finished
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        showNotification("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
    }
}
```

> To execute this worker thread, simply create an instance and call execute():

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

SOURCE: [Keeping Your App Responsive - How to Avoid ANRs](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html#Avoiding)